# Enter two integers a and b (a ≤ b) and output the sum of the squares of all numbers from a to b. (C)

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, sum

Good evening.I need to input two integers a and b (a ≤ b) and output
the sum of the squares of all numbers from a to b.
example:
Enter two numbers:
4 10
The sum of the squares is 361
I would appreciate your help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    printf("Введіть два числа: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

    int N = a;
    while (N < b)
    {
        printf("Сума квадратів: %d\n", a * a + 2 * a * b + b * b);
        N++;
    }
}
```

I don`t know how to write code correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to calculate the sum of squares of numbers in a range. So write for example for the range `[a, b)`

```
unsigned long long int sum = 0;

for ( ; a < b; ++a )
{
    sum += a * a;
}

printf( "Sum = %llu\n", sum );
```

Or if you are considering the range like `[a, b]` then write

```
unsigned long long int sum = 0;

if ( !( b < a ) )
{
    do
    {
        sum += a;
    } while ( a++ != b );
}
```

Comment: Isn't the sum of 4^2 through 10^2 equal to 371? The end condition of the For loop should probably be a <= b.

Comment: @HaveCompiler--WillTravel From the question it is unclear what condition should be used. So I used the same condition as in the question. Usually the last value should not be in the range. In this case if the first and the last values are equal then the range is empty.

Comment: In any event this question is a duplicate of stackoverflow question 70902823.